# Getting ioctl numbers in Swift

Tags: swift, ioctl

what I'm trying to achieve here is getting the ioctl number for ejecting a disk, which I already do in my Bridging Header:

```c
#define DKIOCEJECT  _IO('d', 21)

NSUInteger IOEJECT = DKIOCEJECT;
```

...and that indeed does work for creating an `ioctl` request, what I'm trying to do is just that but in Swift rather than having to use a Bridging Header

In C, I'd usually put something like this to get an `ioctl` number:

```c
#define DKIOCEJECT _IO('d', 21)
```

The above would usually return an `ioctl` number, How can I do something similar but in Swift?

---

Here are all the preprocessor macros:

```
#define _IO(g, n)        _IOC(IOC_VOID, (g), (n), 0)

#define _IOC(inout, group, num, len) \  (inout | ((len & IOCPARM_MASK) << 16) | ((group) << 8) | (num))

#define IOCPARM_MASK    0x1fff          /* parameter length, at most 13 bits */

define IOC_VOID        (__uint32_t)0x20000000
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this btw? The `_IO` macro is for adding new Ioctl numbers to the C source of Linux kernel modules. To my knowledge, you cannot write Linux kernel modules in Swift, so this is moot.

Comment: @Dai Great question Dai, what I'm trying to achieve here is getting the ioctl number for ejecting a disk, which I already do in my Bridging Header: 
`#define DKIOCEJECT                            _IO('d', 21)

NSUInteger IOEJECT = DKIOCEJECT;`
and that indeed does work for creating an ioctl request, what I'm trying to do is just that but in Swift rather than having to use a Bridging Header

Comment: FWIW `DKIOCEJECT` is `25621` or `0x6415` on my machine.

Comment: Unfortunately those return `Inappropriate ioctl for device` :(

Comment: "Inappropriate ioctl for device" - ah yeah, I imagine my Ubuntu box won't behave the same as macOS. So, what is the definition of `#define _IO` on your system?

Comment: `#define _IO(g, n)        _IOC(IOC_VOID, (g), (n), 0)`

And IOC is defined as
`#define _IOC(inout, group, num, len) \
 (inout | ((len & IOCPARM_MASK) << 16) | ((group) << 8) | (num))`
I guess the best I can do here is convert those functions to swift in my own code

Comment: Okay, so what is `#define _IOC`...?

Comment: Yeah sorry for not including that, edited reply to include it

Comment: and `IOCPARM_MASK` ?

Comment: `#define IOCPARM_MASK    0x1fff          /* parameter length, at most 13 bits */`

Comment: And `IOC_VOID` ?

Comment: `#define IOC_VOID        (__uint32_t)0x20000000`
Ok, hopefully that's all of the IOC variables/macros needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the `_IO` macro resolves to a single integer constant, we can follow the preprocessor's logic to reimplement it:

```c
#define DKIOCEJECT                     _IO('d', 21)
#define _IO(g, n)                      _IOC(IOC_VOID, (g), (n), 0)
#define _IOC(inout, group, num, len)   (inout | ((len & IOCPARM_MASK) << 16) | ((group) << 8) | (num))
#define IOC_VOID                       (unsigned long)0x20000000
#define IOCPARM_MASK                   0x1fff
```

Therefore....

```
DKIOCEJECT  == _IO(g: 'd', n: 21)
            == _IOC(IOC_VOID, ('d'), (21), 0)
            == (IOC_VOID | ((0 & IOCPARM_MASK) << 16) | (('d') << 8) | (21))
            == ( 0x20000000 | (0 << 16) | (('d') << 8) | (21) )
            == ( 0x20000000 | 0         | (0x64 << 8)  | 21   )
            == ( 0x20000000             | 0x6400       | 0x15 )
            == 0x20006415

// For reference:
'd'         == 0x64 // asciitable.com
21          == 0x15
```

In Swift as a constant from a literal:

```swift
enum MyIoctrlNumbers {
    static let DKIOCEJECT: UInt = 0x20006415
}
```

---

Swift doesn't support C++-style `constexpr`-expressions, but if you're okay with a runtime-generated `static` value, then try this:

```swift
import Foundation

func getIoctrlNumber( group: Character, n: UInt ) -> UInt {

    let IOC_VOID: UInt = 0x20000000;
    let g       : UInt = UInt( UInt( group.asciiValue! ) << 8 );

    return IOC_VOID | g | n;
}

let asInt = getIoctrlNumber( group: "d", n: 21 );
let asDec = String( asInt, radix: 10 );
let asHex = String( asInt, radix: 16 );
print( "DKIOCEJECT == "   + asDec );
print( "DKIOCEJECT == 0x" + asHex );
```

Gives me this output:

```
Swift version 5.5.1 (swift-5.5.1-RELEASE)                                                   02:11:39 4s
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

DKIOCEJECT == 536896533
DKIOCEJECT == 0x20006415
```

---

Apparently Swift *does* let you populate an `enum`'s values with runtime-init `static` values (not just consts/literals!), so you could have it like so:

```swift
enum MyIoctrlNumbers {

    static let DKIOCEJECT: UInt = getIoctrlNumber( group: "d", n: 21 );
    static let ANOTHER   : Uint = getIoctrlNumber( group: "e", n: 22 );
}
```

and this works fine:

```swift
print( "DKIOCEJECT == "   + String( MyIoctrlNumbers.DKIOCEJECT, radix: 10 ));
print( "DKIOCEJECT == 0x" + String( MyIoctrlNumbers.DKIOCEJECT, radix: 16 ) );
```

Gives me this output:

```
Swift version 5.5.1 (swift-5.5.1-RELEASE)                                                   02:13:31 6s
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu


DKIOCEJECT == 536896533
DKIOCEJECT == 0x20006415
```

Comment: Oh my god! this actually works! thank you so much!

Comment: @Dabezt I've added more code including a `func` that you _can_ use with an `enum` (that surprised me, I thought Swift required compile-time constants for enum values, not static-init values...)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for so long! This will certainly be helpful and allow me to play more with ioctl stuff without Bridging Header shenanigans!!

Comment: I think Swift translates a very limited amount of constant arithmetic in #defines. I use #define compiletimeflag (0>0) or (1>0) all the time because it gets mapped to a Swift Bool that can be used in an if statement.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yup, it seems that Swift doesn't translate some macros.

Before I used @Dai's method of getting the ioctl code, I had defined this macro in the bridging header: `#define DKIOCEJECT _IO('d', 21)` However Swift didn't recognize that macro, so I had to declare this variable in the Bridging Header as well: `NSUInteger IOEJECT = DKIOCEJECT;`, and that did work, thought @Dai's way is obviously way better.

Comment: "though @Dai's way is obviously way better." - it usually is :)

Comment: it's an elegant solution, I did notice how much the code resembles C/C++ more than the usual swift style with all the semicolons, though thats not a bad thing 